# Using two lookup functions for one DIM KEY

Tags: function, plsql, lookup

I have created three lookup functions for three scenarios that can occur within the data.  Each of these functions should return a account_dim_key, the first scenario takes the sr account ID and call data-time from a call table and returns a dim key if the call date-time is between effective start and end dates, the second scenario uses call date(no time) and the third scnario take just uses account id (no date). If the first lookup function returns a -1 then I want to use the second lookup function, and if that returns a -1 then I was to use the third lookup function.  I have been trying to use them in a case statement but in all the scenarios I have tried it always returns the dim key from the second lookup function (in the THEN part of my case statement).  Is it not possible to use three functions in a case statement this way or am I going about it the complete wrong way.

lookup 1

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION LOOKUP_D_ACCT(p_acct_id   IN VARCHAR2, p_date IN DATE)
   RETURN NUMBER
   PARALLEL_ENABLE
IS
   v_dim_id   NUMBER;
BEGIN
   SELECT ACCOUNT_DIM_KEY 
     INTO v_dim_id
     FROM 
          schema.D_ACCOUNT ac
    WHERE     p_acct_id = ac.ID
              AND (p_date BETWEEN ac.EFFECTIVE_START_DT AND ac.EFFECTIVE_END_DT)
          ;

   RETURN v_dim_id;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      RETURN -1;
END LOOKUP_D_ACCT;
/
```

Lookup 2

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION LOOKUP_D_ACCT_TRUNC_DT (p_acct_id   IN VARCHAR2, p_date IN DATE)
   RETURN NUMBER
   PARALLEL_ENABLE
IS
   v_dim_id   NUMBER;
BEGIN
   SELECT MAX(ACCOUNT_DIM_KEY)
     INTO v_dim_id
     FROM 
          schema.D_ACCOUNT ac
    WHERE     p_acct_id = ac.ID
                AND p_date >= TRUNC(ac.EFFECTIVE_START_DT) AND p_date <= TRUNC(ac.EFFECTIVE_END_DT)
          ;

   RETURN v_dim_id;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      RETURN -1;
END;
/
```

Lookup 3

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION LOOKUP_D_ACCT_NO_DT (p_acct_id   IN VARCHAR2)
   --LOOKUP FUNCTION TO PASS THROUGH FIELD_ALIGN_DIM_ID WITH DATE CRITERIA
   --new one for practice load
   --dated 8/31
   RETURN NUMBER
   PARALLEL_ENABLE
IS
   v_dim_id   NUMBER;
BEGIN
   SELECT ACCOUNT_DIM_KEY
     INTO v_dim_id
     FROM 
          schema.D_ACCOUNT ac
    WHERE     p_acct_id = ac.ID
          ;

   RETURN v_dim_id;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      RETURN -1;
END;
/
```

The select of my procedure looks like this:

```
SELECT cl.id,
       cl.account_vod__c,
       cl.call_date_vod__c,
       cl.call_datetime_vod__c,
       (CASE
           WHEN NVL (
                   LOOKUP_D_ACCT(cl.ACCOUNT_VOD__C,
                                        CL.CALL_DATETIME_VOD__C),
                   -1) = -1
           --lookup 1
           THEN
              NVL (
                 LOOKUP_ACCT_TRUNC_DT (cl.ACCOUNT_VOD__C,
                                          CL.CALL_DATE_VOD__C),
                 -1)
           --lookup 2
           WHEN NVL (
                   LOOKUP_ACCT_TRUNC_DT (cl.ACCOUNT_VOD__C,
                                            CL.CALL_DATE_VOD__C),
                   -1) = -1
           THEN
              NVL (LOOKUP_D_ACCT_NO_DT (cl.ACCOUNT_VOD__C), -1)
           --lookup 3
           ELSE -3
        END)
          AS ACCOUNT_DIM_KEY,
       LOOKUP_D_ACCT_VEEVA (cl.ACCOUNT_VOD__C, CL.CALL_DATETIME_VOD__C)
          AS DTIME_DIM_KEY,
       --lookup 1
       LOOKUP_ACCOUNT_DIM_TEST (cl.ACCOUNT_VOD__C, CL.CALL_DATE_VOD__C)
          AS DT_DIM_KEY,
       --lookup 2
       LOOKUP_D_ACCT_VEEVA_NO_DT (cl.ACCOUNT_VOD__C) AS NODT_DIM_KEY
  --lookup 3
  FROM schema.CALLTABLE CL
 WHERE CL.ID IN ('a043600000Bija3AAB')
```

I would expect the 'ACCOUNT_DIM_KEY' field to always be populated with the functions from lookup 1, 2, or 3
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCvQ4.jpg)

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you want the first non-null value from the three functions, that sounds like you need a `coalesce`.

Comment: Using coalesce I only get the results from my first lookup.  I need it to use the 1st lookup, if thats -1 then the 2nd lookup and if 2nd lookup = -1 then 3rd lookup.  Does coalesce not work in this scenario because of the -1 values?

Comment: Oh, OK. If you want the first value that isn't -1 then you'll need to nest `case` statements, i.e. start another `case` inside the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to pass all the chain of your conditions, then you shouldn't use  `case` statement, but in series check each condition:

```
if (NVL (LOOKUP_D_ACCT(cl.ACCOUNT_VOD__C, CL.CALL_DATETIME_VOD__C), -1) = -1) then 
    if (NVL ( LOOKUP_ACCT_TRUNC_DT (cl.ACCOUNT_VOD__C, CL.CALL_DATE_VOD__C), -1) = -1 ) then 
      if (NVL (LOOKUP_D_ACCT_NO_DT (cl.ACCOUNT_VOD__C), -1) = -1) then 
        -- if third func returned -1
      else 
        -- action if third case
      end if;
    else
      --action if second case
    end if;
  else
    --action if first case
end if;
```

**UPD**
Sure, if it's a **SQL** not a PL/SQL, than you should use nested `case`, as has been said:

```
SELECT 
       (CASE
           WHEN NVL (
                   LOOKUP_D_ACCT(cl.ACCOUNT_VOD__C,
                                        CL.CALL_DATETIME_VOD__C),
                   -1) = -1
           --lookup 1
           THEN
              CASE
                WHEN                     
                  NVL (
                     LOOKUP_ACCT_TRUNC_DT (cl.ACCOUNT_VOD__C,
                                              CL.CALL_DATE_VOD__C),
                     -1)= -1

                THEN 
                  NVL (LOOKUP_D_ACCT_NO_DT (cl.ACCOUNT_VOD__C), -1)                 
                ELSE -3
              END
           WHEN NVL (
                   LOOKUP_ACCT_TRUNC_DT (cl.ACCOUNT_VOD__C,
                                            CL.CALL_DATE_VOD__C),
                   -1) = -1
           THEN
              NVL (LOOKUP_D_ACCT_NO_DT (cl.ACCOUNT_VOD__C), -1)
           --lookup 3
           ELSE -3
        END)
          AS ACCOUNT_DIM_KEY,
       LOOKUP_D_ACCT_VEEVA (cl.ACCOUNT_VOD__C, CL.CALL_DATETIME_VOD__C)
          AS DTIME_DIM_KEY,
       --lookup 1
       LOOKUP_ACCOUNT_DIM_TEST (cl.ACCOUNT_VOD__C, CL.CALL_DATE_VOD__C)
          AS DT_DIM_KEY,
       --lookup 2
       LOOKUP_D_ACCT_VEEVA_NO_DT (cl.ACCOUNT_VOD__C) AS NODT_DIM_KEY
  --lookup 3
  FROM schema.CALLTABLE CL
 WHERE CL.ID IN ('a043600000Bija3AAB')
```

Comment: this worked great exactly as I was expecting.  Thank you!